# Div css transition not collapsing on toggle

Tags: css, angular, animation

I want to toggle this div to expand and collapse on click. The transition for the expand works, however I cannot figure out how to transition the collapse. I would like to use max-height in order to have dynamic (large or small) content inside of my div.

div.component.html

```
<div
[ngClass]="{'expand': divClass, 'collapse': !divClass}"
(click)="divClass = !divClass"
class="a">
</div>
```

div.component.css

```
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

.expand {
    background-color: red;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

.collapse {
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}
```

Comment: Made you a StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-2s3srf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) I'm assuming you want the collapse a bit slower huh?

Comment: @BSchnitzel there is still no transition on collapse in your example

Comment: Haven't solved it just made you one to use here. Try editing your main post and adding it. Other people will then fork it and try to help. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the transition to transition-duration..just css stuff

div.component.css

```
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.expand {
    background-color: red;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

.collapse {
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

And here is the [Demo](https://angular-playground-xurmps.stackblitz.io) and the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-xurmps) I forked showing it working

Comment: hmm, I wonder why that worked. Very strange indeed - Thank you!